# Calibration error

Tags: touchscreen

I use this documentation for touchscreen calibration https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen
The drivers have already been installed by the OS
I start execution from the Calibration point
xinput_calibrator --output-type xinput
I hit targets
Then I get the following error message
[image]
How to correctly and accurately calibrate the screen on ubuntu mate 22.04?